# Как сделать сохранение данных C# приложения в xml в вебе?

Tags: c#

Есть небольшое приложение на C# с функцией сохранения данных в xml файл. На локальной машине с сохранением и чтением проблем нет, но была поставлена задача написать серверную часть, так что бы работа с файлом была возможна и в вебе.

Прошу показать простой каркас подобного кода или дать ссылки на ресурсы где этот вопрос хорошо "разжеван".

Answer (score 1):

Xml Web Services, WCF

Answer (score 1):

Я бы взял новый [Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com) (это WCF REST).